# How to get the size of a list of documents in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working PHP MongoDB. I am looking for a way to search for a list of documents and find the bsonsize of them in one value. The code below only calculates a single document size. Even if I use Object.bsonsize(db.{$collectionName}.find(), it only gets the cursor right? Is there any way to calculate this without iterating the cursor?

Iterating the cursor to do this is too slow.

Thanks

```
function documentSizeChecker($collectionName,Array $Criteria){
    $connection = db_connect();
    $jsonCriteria = json_encode($Criteria);
    $code = "function(){
    return Object.bsonsize(db.{$collectionName}.findOne({$jsonCriteria}))
  }";

    $resp = $connection->execute($code);
    return $resp["retval"];
}
```

Comment: Given that you will pass the criteria to search the documents, I don't see any other way of getting the total size of the list of documents returned than iterating the cursor.

Comment: Is there any Map/Reduce way of doing it?